# posts update automaticlly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creacting an admin zone for a blog I'm building. For some reason, the database is inserted with the last information I've submitted each time I refresh the page, instead of whenever I click "submit".

This is the page itself:

```
<?php
//send uploaded files to mysql
include_once 'conn.php';
include_once 'submit.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your admin page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Admin page</h1>
    <h2>upload text</h2>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label>Header</label>
        <input type="header" name="header" required><br>
        <label>Text</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" required><br>
        <label>Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

This is the submit.php file:

```
<?php
include_once 'conn.php';
$header = $_POST['header'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$file_get = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$file_to_saved = "uploads/".$file_get;
move_uploaded_file($temp, $file_to_saved);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $insert = ("INSERT INTO posts (postHeader,postText,picture) VALUES ('$header','$text','$file_to_saved')");
   if ($link->query($insert) === TRUE) {
       echo "record created succesfully";
   } else{
    echo "something went wrong with the file";
   }

  }
```

Comment: First, i'm ok not responding to your problem, becarfull to SQL Injection in your code take a look here : https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Comment: It's when you made refresh of your browser or when you go to first time in the page ?

Comment: when I refresh the page

Comment: so it's normal when you reload the page the post was resend by your browser. To avoid this you need to use unique Token.

Comment: you can take inspiration from this : https://code-boxx.com/simple-csrf-token-php/